# Android Studio structure changed after refactoring App folder

Tags: android, android-studio

After I did refactor application name `app` to `prevent` my `Android` project view lost its functionality.

[image]

All icons become grey and some folders that are usually not visible in this view are visible. I also miss `new -> Activity` in content menu.

How to fix that?

Comment: @JakeB Now it's proper.

Comment: Did you edit the configuration as such you change main module name you need to set the configuration to that.

Answer (score 0):

You did not refactor Application name you refactored folder inside your project.
You should undo that.
And if you wish to refactor project name switch from android tab to project tab and then refactor rename.

[image]